# Image over another image in a smaller div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I know that there have been similar questions, but mine is a little special.
In a PhoneGap application with jQuery Mobile I want to set an image over another in a div,  images are with the same width and height.

I need to set the images with Javascript/jQuery after an AJAX request. 
The div's width is smaller than the images' width, so I have used `overflow:hidden`, and  by the images `margin: 0 -100%`, but this way only the first image is set middle, the second 
is below the first one.

I have tried with `position:absolute` and `top:-(firstImageHeight)`

with the same result.

CSS:

```
#imgdiv{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 90%;
    position: relative;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var html= "<img src=" + obj.file + " id=" + "imageID" + " />";

html += "<img src=" + obj.file + " id=" + "maskID" + " />";

$('#imgdiv').html(html);

$("#imageID").css({"height":"100%", "margin":"0 -100%","z-index":"1"});

var imgHeight = $("#imageID").get(0).height;

$("#maskID").css({"height":"100%", "margin":"0 -100%","z-index":"3","position":"absolute", "top":-(imgHeight)});
```

Comment: Can you show some fiddle please?

Comment: If what you want is to mask the bottom image with the top one, consider using [CSS masks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/). It seems fairly [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=mask) in mobile browsers and would avoid the whole layering issue.

Comment: @martineno: Can I use it with .jpg and .png images as well?

Comment: Yes, the `mask-image` property can be a .jpg or .png image. Of course, since it is an alpha mask, the image that specifies the mask should be greyscale.

Answer (score 1):

with your code, the resulting html is something like:

```
<div id="imgdiv">
    <img src="source 1" id="imageID"/>
    <img src="source 2" id="maskID"/>
</div>
```

but your css only defines the position of #imgdiv. this means, the images inside your imgdiv are - according to their position - treated like normal textflow. to position them correctly, you have to define their position via css. either with #imgdiv > img {} or - the way i prefer, with giving them a classname.

since i don't have your image objects, i included some fix image links - but i guess, you could handle this, while adapting the solution to your code.

```
var html= '<img class="overlayImg" src="http://s21.postimg.org/6iqdjw3vr/excmark.png" id="imageID"/>';
html += '<img class="overlayImg" src="http://s21.postimg.org/lq6d48vqf/redcircle.png" id="maskID"/>';

$('#imgdiv').html(html);
```

the we'd like to center the image inside the div. therefore, we need the div's height and width, and the images height and width:

```
firstImgLeftPos = ($('#imgdiv').width() - $('#imageID').width())/2;
firstImgTopPos = ($('#imgdiv').height() - $('#imageID').height())/2;

scndImgLeftPos = ($('#imgdiv').width() - $('#maskID').width())/2;
scndImgTopPos = ($('#imgdiv').height() - $('#maskID').height())/2;

$("#imageID").css({ "top" : firstImgTopPos, "left" : firstImgLeftPos});
$("#maskID").css({ "top" : scndImgTopPos, "left" : scndImgLeftPos});
```

also, since i don't know the rest of your page and the needed dimensions, i changed the imgdiv dimensions via css into fixed values and added a red border, to make the div visible. since the images are now positioned absolute, the text-aling and vertical-align for the inner div, get ignored, so i deleted them.
and of course, added the css definition for the new class .overlayImg.

```
#imgdiv{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 240px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}

.overlayImg{
    position: absolute;
}
```

since my images are transparent, z-index isn't needed. 
you can add this in your css by using your id's, though.

see the working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bobpd9e3/3/

Comment: I have a problem. The first image is set in the middle but the second remains on the left side of the div. I have written this: $("#maskID").css("left",secondImageLeftPos); and when I check it with this: console.log($("#maskID").css("left")); it returns that its left property is set.

Comment: sry for abandoning this thread, i've been offline for a week... currently i don't now if i get your problem right. if the pos is set, then it should center correctly. have you set the position to 'absolute'?